# Recalculate razor computed viewmodel properties without reload page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I know I can NOT recalculate a server side viewmodel property which is computed from other server side viewmodel properties without reloading the page displaying the computed properties.

So whats the alternative with the least effort but maximum effectivity?

1) Write some jquery update functions which are called on the page reload/load and do not create the computed properties on the server side viewmodels? Thats a workaround...

2) If I would introduce knockoutJS then imho razor mvc would not make sense... I do not want server AND client side viewmodels. Thats a mess...

So is the conclusion if I have many client-side real-time updates of properties and do not want to make a browser request with razor then I should rather choose ASP.NET Web API and go into direction SPA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So is the conclusion if I have many client-side real-time updates of
>   properties and do not want to make a browser request with razor then I
>   should rather choose ASP.NET Web API and go into direction SPA?

It depends on who is performing the update. If it is the end user and you are looking for a maximum interactivity, then yes, SPA is the way to go. In this case I agree with you that having server side and client side view models is redundant.

If on the other hand the updates are happening on the server and you want to notify the client as soon as possible then you might take a look at HTML 5 WebSockets and [`SignalR`](http://www.asp.net/signalr) which provide you with push notifications.

Comment: Well the update would happen if the Index.html with the ListViewModel would be reloaded because then the whole database are fetched and the server side viewmodels created + properties computed etc... But when you have a jquery create dialog over the Index.html you do not reload the Index.html. So the solution seem to put the Create/Edit views not over the Index.html in a dialog rather you create/update then do a redirect to the Index.html. But thats not a good user experience... Just imagine entering 1000 employees base data means 1000 times redirect to the Index.html view :P

Comment: Before I use WebSockets + SignalR just to eliminate the deficit of mvc/razor I would really rather look into a SPA. But I have to put together a cool mvc sample :/ although mvc is not that cool... ;-)